# how to get script location in pyspark jupyter kernel

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook

**My Problem:**

I would like to get the directory of the current jupyter script inside jupyter notebook when I am using the pyspark kernel.

**What I have tried:**

When the pyspark kernel is running, I can access environment variables in two ways: using *os* and I get the system environment variables and using *%env* getting the jupyter pyspark kernel global variables. In the second one, there is a variable called JPY_SESSION_NAME, which could help me to solve my problem. However, I cannot save this value in a variable in the jupyter notebook.

Any idea to solve the problem?

Comment: Coincidentally I'm trying to solve the same problem for GoNB (a kernel for Go). The JPY_SESSION_NAME is an exported variable, I would expect you could read it with `os.getenv`, but I haven't worked in pyspark, so I'm not sure if it copies over these env variables to the workers.

Now the worst problem is that a notebook can be renamed by the client (or saved as a different name). I'm not sure the kernel is informed of that, and JPY_SESSION_NAME won't be magically updated ...